# Which one is more efficient: boolean or binary integer?

Tags: php, performance, memory, integer, boolean

I have to store a binary value in a variable or an array element, to indicate that an option is enabled or disabled.

I believe using "Yes" or "No" is less efficient than 1 or 0 (or empty), but I wonder whether there's any difference between 1/0 and TRUE/FALSE, in terms of performance or memory usage or anything else.

Between

```
$option = 1; # if the option is enabled
$option = 0; # if the option is disabled OR
$option = ""; # if the option is disabled
```

and

```
$option = TRUE; # if the option is enabled
$option = FALSE; # if the option is disabled
```

which way is recommended? Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you performed any benchmarking yourself?

Comment: No practical difference whatsoever. If for some unimaginable reason 1/0 is better, surely PHP would trivially optimize by handling boolean values internally as integers.

Comment: Never use strings like "yes" and "no" or "true" and "false" to store binary values. Always use a format which correctly evaluates in a boolean context. E.g., `(string) "false"` is true, so you don't want to use that.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I didn't do benchmarking, but I did some research and didn't find answers. Doing benchmarking can be a good idea but I'm not sure how to do that other than checking how long it takes to run the script in the browser. However, on other occasions I have seen that it's quite variable without changing anything in the script.

Comment: Alex confirms that strings are not a good idea, and I understand from JJJ's answer that TRUE/FALSE and 1/0 would be pretty much equivalent. In fact, I've seen that SQLite turns TRUE/FALSE values to 1/0 when inserting data. If using 1/0 integers, I'm still not sure, though, whether 0, NULL and "" (empty string) would be equivalent, when the value is not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220529/2095577) suggests that zero, null and empty are equivalent, and this answer[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40325850/2095577) suggests that 1 and true are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In the 'Anything else' category; a human will immediately understand if option is a Boolean type from Yes/No/True/False/On/Off, but not from 0/1, which can be a numerical option as well. This issue can be remedied by naming the option with suffix like _bool that indicates that it is a Boolean option and not an Integer option, this is then visible and obvious both in the code and any possible configuration file for options.